# startfile" filepath should be string, bytes or os.Pathlike, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I am new to python and have been trying to do some project but i have been stuck on this for a while now i hope i can get help.

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
   result = []

   for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      if filename in files:
         result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return result

find = find_files("Among Us.exe","D:")

os.startfile(find)
```

The error is:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
```

Comment: `find_files` returns a list object. Where as `os.startfile` expect string object as argument.

Comment: Please post the *complete* traceback, not just the last line. You're making it harder to answer your question for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is rather simple: you're trying to give a function expecting a string, a list.

Either pick an index from the list or make `find_files` return a string. If there's supposed to be one index, pick 0

Example

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
   result = []

   for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      if filename in files:
         result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return result

find = find_files("Among Us.exe","D:")

os.startfile(find[0])
```

However I think this is more what you're looking for:

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):    
   for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
      if filename in files:
         return os.path.join(root, filename)

find = find_files("Among Us.exe","D:")

os.startfile(find)
```